# DETS concurrency? (Erlang)

Tags: concurrency, erlang, datastore

I know that ETS has limited concurrency, for instance two writes to the same row at the same time aren't going to collide.  But I can't seem to find out this sort of information for DETS.  Does anyone know?

Note that I'm not asking about DETS running under the auspices of Mnesia, and I'm not asking about any particular scheme - say assigning a single process per row of the DETS table.  I just want to know what the limited concurrency guarantees of DETS are, if any.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd just avoid DETS because of its size limitations and tendency to corrupt

Comment: I'd like to avoid it, but because of performance requirements, mnesia transactions and locking isn't going to cut it, so I have a plan to shard the crap out of it to deal with the size limitation issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, DETS currently does not support concurrency.

From the [`dets` manual](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dets.html) (my highlights):

> It is worth noting that the ordered_set type present in Ets is not yet
>   implemented by Dets, neither is the limited support for concurrent
>   updates which makes a sequence of first and next calls safe to use on
>   fixed Ets tables. **Both these features will be implemented by Dets in a
>   future release of Erlang/OTP. Until then, the Mnesia application (or
>   some user implemented method for locking) has to be used to implement
>   safe concurrency**. Currently, no library of Erlang/OTP has support for
>   ordered disk based term storage.

Comment: Thanks - I had seen that in the docs earlier, however it is unclear and somewhat appears to be talking about either ordered sets, or use of first and next.  For this particular application I don't need ordered set or first/next, I just need the ability of multiple processes to add new records concurrently.  I did run a test where 100 processes all write a new record at the same time, and it worked, however I would like to know whether it is GUARANTEED to work

Comment: Good point. Just from trying it, it seems opening a DETS table spawns a child process under `dets_sup` in the kernel. However, writing to a table does not change that process at all. That leads me to believe that writes are done directly to the file. I'm not sure, but I think writing to a file is "thread safe" in Erlang (no documentation there either, of course). The order might not be guaranteed, but each write should be performed atomically.

Comment: In general, I think there are very few (if any at all) standard libraries that are not "thread safe", due to the way Erlang works. Locking and consistency is another matter, of course.